# How to add a prop's value to a class' instance only when the prop name is a class field

Tags: typescript, typescript-typings

Imagine I have something like this

```js
export default class Record {
  date: Date = new Date()
  temperature?: number
  humidity?: number
  windDirection?: string
  // etc
}
```

Where all records will always have a date, but then they can have one or more other fields.

I have a database with records, but I don't know what are the props they have. I know they'll have a date, and hopefully one or more of the other properties.

I'd like to iterate over the database document properties and set only the properties that have some value.

I was hoping a constructor like the following would work, but it doesn't.

```js
constructor(item: any) {
  for (const prop in item) {
    if (prop in Record) {
      this[prop] = item[prop]
    }
  }
}
```

That gives an error on the line where I do `this[prop] = item[prop]`. The error I get is: `Element implicitly has an 'any' type because expression of type 'string' can't be used to index type 'Record'. No index signature with a parameter of type 'string' was found on type 'Record'`

When I do this, only the date is picked, the rest of the props are skipped. I'm not sure why, but probably because date is the only non-optional field?

I was hoping this would be a common way of parsing db documents into TypeScript objects. Is there a standard way of doing this?

#### How can I check that a prop from the db doc would exist in a Record instance?

**bonus points**

This wouldn't be the main question, but now that we're here, is there a way to enforce that at least one of temperature, humidity, etc are not undefined? So we don't have a record with just a date.

Comment: 1. Does it really need to be a class instance? 2. Is your date saved in the DB document? Because as of now, your Record instance's 'date' property is set to "now" when you initialize your Record object (and is propably overwritten in your for-loop).

Comment: 1. No, it could be something else if it makes more sense. I thought using a class is the best way for the compiler to figure out types, but I'm fairly new to TS and could be totally wrong. 2. Yes, the db docs have a date. That default is for when I create a record on the client